# Block a Ball at a curved intersection? [Java]

Tags: java, line, curve, intersect

I want to have a curved shield in front of my space ship to block incoming attacks.

Any ideas on how to use an image and make it only detect where the pixels are or something similar? Even if I have two objects, being the image and something else like a curved line, this should be possible right? Thanks!

Comment: The collision detection surely won't be part of the GUI or view but rather part of the model, right?

Comment: Any NASA guys want to help user516664 fortify his space craft against attack with a pixel shield?

Comment: @Hovercraft basically - @coreyward haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a real MVC (Model-View-Controller) design you would have a model that just describes where your spaceship is and perhaps a math formula describing your shield. Then the view component draws images based on that. If you check for collision you don't need to work on pixels. You can calculate the path of a shot (like the path the shot has moved since the last cycle of your game engine which will only cover milliseconds) and then check whether it collided with anything using plain math.

Comment: That sounds like a good Idea... I guess that would be possible... any tuts you know of with advanced math used in it?

Comment: @user516664: Sorry, I don't know a tutorial. Though I guess you will sooner or late have to cope with the problem of calculating all fields a bullet or another object that was covered. You may find the algorithm of bresenham coming in very handy at this point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm / For your question: Try google. If nothing comes up, start a new question asking for ressources on stackoverflow ;-).

Answer (score 0):

> Any tutorials…?

This [kinetic model](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/kineticmodel) of elastic collisions uses an MVC design, and this paper on [*2-Dimensional Elastic Collisions*](http://www.vobarian.com/collisions/) may be instructive.